# Cannot run jar file of JavaFX program. It's just won't run

Tags: java, javafx, jar, executable-jar

Basically, I did a program in Intelijj Idea with JavaFX and in IDE it works, but when I made an artifact with modules and dependencies, jar file won't run. When I'm trying to run it with `java -jar myProgram.jar` it says that JavaFX elements are missing. But in IDE it's working.

Comment: Are the required jars in your classpath?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca i don't know which jars it requires, I connected javaFx library in dependencies

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca i have this in the classpath : --module-path "D:\CODE\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib" --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml. I cannot understand why it's running in IDE, but won't run from jar file

Comment: a) please do some (thorough!) research - there are tons of related questions/resources on the web - before asking. b) no screenshots of text! c) clarify the question by editing (vs. in comments)

Answer (score 0):

So I found solution on Youtube
link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HuFOCEHh8Zg
I just needed to add .dll files from javafx's bin folder, when i was making an artifact.